# How to add date picker control to my toolbox

Tags: asp.net

I am using visual studio 2005 and I have added Datepicker dll in my bin folder.And By doing right click on solution Explorer  Add:references,choosed the that dll.But I want display that control in my toolbar.Does I need to create tab for it.Or it automatically get created.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to go to your toolbox then right click anywhere in the toolbox area click choose item and then you can sleect your server control dll from there and it should appear in your toolbox

Comment: Great to hear can you please mark this question as resolved my clicking on the tick on the left side of this answer. Thanks

Comment: I don't have that much reputation.Sorry

Comment: You don't need rep to select the answer, there can be a time delay however

Answer (score 0):

For Visual Studio information always check [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165354.aspx) first  ;-)

HTH.

Comment: Hmm. There has been an outbreak of downvoting against my account this last week or so, I'm suspicious and was hoping the process that would pick up a pattern of malicious downvotes would pick these up. Will the process still run regardless of your manual check on this question?